# Dock icon in Mountain Lion disappears for open app

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, dock

This is a perplexing issue: a program icon for a RUNNING program disappears from my Mountain Lion (10.8.1) Dock once the documents it was displaying are closed.

The offending App is TextEdit, although I suspect this will also happen in other apps. I'll be editing a text file, then close the window using the red "x" button in the top left, and as expected the window will close and the TextEdit icon will remain in the Dock with the little blue dot underneath. But wait a few seconds, and the Dock icon disappears!

I know that it's still running, because I can see the process in Activity Monitor. So what gives? Does anyone know how to make running applications remain in the Dock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this might be a bug. I currently have Disk Utility running. I can see the application, but it isn't showing in the Dock, nor does it show in Mission Control or the Cmd+Tab list. Killing the Dock or relaunching the Finder fixes the problem temporarily. I was kind of hoping this would be fixed in 10.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the dock using any one of the below procedures.

1.Open terminal and type

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock
killall Dock
```

OR

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.{db,plist}
killall Dock
```

Hope this helps you.